# AWS disable network access between tenants

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to AWS and I'm trying to build an application that allows customers to spawn up machines for setting up database clusters

Users are free to SSH into their machines, however there should be no connectivity between m1 & m2 where m1 is the cluster of machines tenant t1 owns while m2 is the cluster of machines tenant t2 owns

I did figure out that security groups is the answer to this, however their quota is limited which made me think is my approach even right? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Which quota are you referring to? The default security group quota is 2500, and you can have that increased. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, I just didn't want to pay for something (after increasing the quota) just to later realize a solution to this was something different entirely :D Just wanted guidance for solving this. Security groups should be fine for now & I can safely start with the default limit of 2500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you probably want to separate your clients by giving each one its own AWS account (using organizations) or at the very least by creating a separate VPC for each client.

Comment: VPC Quota is much more limited than Security Groups. Let me check Organizations. In the end, it totally could be adding more bucks :D AWS has to make money somehow right? I just wanted to confirm if there was something basic that I am missing like maybe OS's provided something out of the box for what I wanted to do @chris

Comment: @FaizHalde:  There is no charge for either an account or a VPC, so this is not a cost consideration.  And you can easily get an increase in the number of available VPCs - I just did this on a new account, and it was approved within 10 minutes.

Comment: oh that's wonderful. i don't know what the implications of multiple VPC would be in terms of my application level logic, but why would you prefer different VPC for each client vs security group for segregating the client machines?

Comment: I know the question is intended for Chris, but VPC is more preferable in my opinion.

Comment: To answer that question in detail, I would need more information about the type of infrastructure you're using, the type of data, client access details, and the consequences of unauthorized access to data or infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

If the Database clusters you intend to build are supported by [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/), this might be a better approach at managing DB instances at scale. You can then create IAM roles specific to customers and their clusters and they can remotely change configurations of their instances without the need to SSH.

Another better approach would be to have a VPC for each client and either create a VPN tunnel back to their on-prem (where they'll SSH from) or setup a public jump box and whitelist source IPs. This creates a more secure boundary for SSH, arguably other areas as well. You'll likely need to request an increase above the default [5 VPCs per region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-vpcs-subnets) limit.

I'd also strongly advise engaging with a Cloud Network/Security specialist, before implementing any option, there's bound to be nuances here and there.